# AWS Ec2 instance (ubuntu) instance not showing elastic ip address

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-elastic-ip, aws-ec2

I have allocated an elastic IP address to an AWS Ec2 (ubuntu) instance. But when i am running the 'ip address show' command, it only displayes the public IPV4 address, not showing the Associated elastic IP. How can i see the EIP in the command line?